# adding free products with a simple product?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add some freebies with a product? Is there an option to do that?

I referred many tutorials and not finding answer,

Answer (score 0):

custom option for product could be helpful in your situation. Please check the following link: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-product-option-and-its-use-case-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This custom option with provide an option user to select. But freebies need not any selection option. How can I do that with custom option